# Growing plant (e.g. date palm) from the seed of the dried fruit?

Tags: houseplants, fruit-trees, germination, seed-saving

I would like to grow date palm from the seed as a house plant in my flat. I have no access to the fresh date fruit, I have access to the dried date fruit only with the seede (core). Can I use the seed from the dried date to grow plant? Does the fruit/date drying process inactivates/kills the seed or does the seeds growth ability stays inact?

Of course, I have searched Google, but it has some standard answers (possible yes) but they give no explanation of process of producing dried date and they don't have impression of credibility or understanding.

Comment: I guess it depends what technology was used. If you have naturally dried dates (as sold in the Middle East where they are grown) they would probably germinate OK, but the most of the boxes of dates sold at Christmas period in the UK are obviously processed (e.g. glazed with sugar syrup) so who knows if they are still fertile.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to find out is to try. Save several seeds and  put them in water for a week; change the water daily so  they don't go mouldy,  and keep them somewhere that isn't cold. After that, plant them into potting soil, spaced apart, water the  pot and stand it on a sunny  windowsill. Water again only when the surface of the soil feels dry  to the touch. It can take several weeks for any growth to start, but if you get to 6 months and nothing's happened, then it's likely the seeds are not viable. Info here https://joybileefarm.com/grow-date-tree/